# Is it possible to add debug symbols to an existing C++ .so (shared library)?

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, g++, .so

I have a work project that relies on a very large, inherited C++ shared library that was released without debug symbols and we only have the .h includes. Often, there is a need to see how those functions act on values passed in but debugging in gdb skips over those functions. Is it possible for me to build the sources myself to ensure the debug symbols are there? I have tried adding the `-g` flag to the `CXXFLAGS` section in my Makefile but that didn't seem to do it. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In order to generate debug symbols you'll need complete source code.

Comment: @Cpt_Shiner I think your two options here would be to get the debug symbols for your release from the release's supplier (better debug using debug release) or get the source code and recompile (that means cpp files, not only headers).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to build the sources myself to ensure the debug symbols are there?

If you *have* the sources, then yes.

> I have tried adding the -g flag to the CXXFLAGS section in my Makefile but that didn't seem to do it.

Assuming that by "my Makefile" you mean the `Makefile` which builds the library, and not the `Makefile` which builds your application, adding `-g` should be all that's required.

"Didn't seem to do it" can mean any number of things.

- Did you add `-g` to the right place?
- Did the build succeed?
- Did you arrange for the application to use the newly-built library?

There is not enough info in your question to guess.